# Effective method of collecting SKU level forecasts from external customers?

Tags: python, powerquery, forecasting

I need to collect and collate SKU level forecasts from around 30 customers. It needs to be phased for the next 12 months, and cover three separate methods of supply for a wide array of products.
There needs to be some method of request and receipt of these forecasts, that don't involve manually emailing 30 customers individually.
The range and pricing needs to be updated each time it is requested.
Any previous iteration of the customer's forecast needs to be included in the request, as a starting point.

Current process involves building an Excel file with the current range for each customer. Range and pricing are updated, any existing forecast is entered into the file and this is emailed out.
The main problem with this process is that it is too manual and intensive on both sides; it takes a really long time to create and then distribute the files, and then once received, customers don't want to fill them in because they're too unwieldy.

What I'm ultimately looking for is an efficient and effective way to gather forecasts from customers, that's as user friendly as I can make it. The tools available to me are somewhat limited; I have Excel, Power Query and Python. I could maybe get access to SQL.

Would appreciate any advice that can be offered, if anyone has experience with a similar problem.